# Re-size DOJO table with browser window

Tags: css, dojo

I have a DOJO table in my web-page. When the browser is re-sized, the table is not getting re-sized. I want it to get re-sized when the browser window is re-sized. How can I do that?

```
var gridLayout = [ 
{
    name : "S. No.",
    classes : "title",
    width : "70px",
    get : siFormatter,
    filterable : false
}, {
    name : "Site Id",
    classes : "title",
    field : "siteId",
    width : "70px"
}, {
    name : "IP/Phone No.",
    classes : "title",
    field : "devType",
    width : "120px"
}, {
    name : 'Site Name',
    classes : "title",
    field : "name",
    fields : [ 'company', 'name' ],
    formatter : formatLink,
    width : "110px"
}, {
    name : "Product",
    classes : "title",
    field : "smsCode",
    width : "100px"
}, {
    name : "Date & Time",
    classes : "title",
    field : "date",
    width : "140px"
}, {
    name : 'Status',
    classes : "title",
    field : "statusMessage",
    fields : [ 'statusMessage', 'statusMessageColor' ],
    formatter : formatLink1,
    width : "140px"
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute `initialWidth` with percentage plus the attribute `autoWidth`:

```
var grid = new DataGrid({
    id: 'grid',
    store: store,
    structure: layout,
    autoWidth: true,
    initialWidth: "80%"});
```

Take a look at [dojox.grid.DataGrid](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html) for details and this [demo](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/test_data_grid_autowidth.html).

Comment: can you give me a sample fiddle?

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LpD4S/7/). most of the code comes from [dojox.grid.DataGrid](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#dojox-grid-datagrid) reference guide